# Spring service with in-memory list

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to have a service which keeps a list inmemory so I don't need to access the database everytime. The service is accessed by a controller. Is this a valid approach or am I missing something? What about concurrent access here (from the controller)? Is this (stateful service) an anti-pattern?

```
@Service
public class ServiceCached {
    private List<SomeObject> someObjects;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initOnce() {
        someObjects = /** longer running loading methodd **/
    }

    public List<SomeObject> retrieveObjects() {
        return someObjects;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your list is fix ?

Comment: If the list doesn't change why do you worry about concurrency?

Comment: The list will be read only. I'm worrying more about the statefulness. Was just asking if I am missing something.

Comment: ACtually this sounds like if you need some kind of `Cache`...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it an anti-pattern, but in my opinion loading the list from the database in a `@PostConstruct` method is not a good idea as you slow down the start up of your application, I'd rather use a lazy loading mechanism, but this would potentially introduce some concurrent access issues that would need to be handled.

In your example concurrent access from the controller should not be a problem as the list is loaded from a `@PostConstruct` method and the controller would depend on this service, therefore this service would need to be fully constructed before it is injected into the controller, therefore the list would already be loaded.

Preferably I'd suggest using Spring Caching: [Caching Data with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/), [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html), [Useful guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)

Usage example:

```
@Cacheable("books")
public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
    simulateSlowService();
    return new Book(isbn, "Some book");
}
```

This way you do not need to take care of loading and evicting the objects. Once set up, the caching framework will take care of this for you.